# Calculate cardinality of 8-digit strings composed of zeros and ones

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations

How can i calculate cardinality of a set made of 8-digit strings composed of zeros and ones? In general, assuming that digits can repeats.

**My attempt**

Let $D$ be the domain composed only by one or zero

$D = \{0,1\}$

maybe I should calculate the ordered selection of $k=8$ and $n=2$?

so $D'_{n,k} = n^k = 2^8 = 256$

Is that correct?

Comment: The numerical answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes it's only a self-confidence matter. :D

Comment: You are welcome. From my viewpoint, perhaps your notation distances you a little too much from what is a very concrete problem.